# Pivot Table won't show correct data relating to the row names

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I'm trying to create a pivot table to tell me how many people are coming to different parts of a bachelor party. When I select the "Row Labels", I select that of "Coming Zorb" as they are the same labels for both columns of data.

However, the data reflects the "Coming Zorb" values in both columns in the pivot table, including "Coming Camping". When I switch the "Row Labels" to "Coming Camping" the data reflects the camping data in both columns.

There should be one more "No" and one less "Yes" in the "Coming Zorb" column.

How do I get the pivot table to reflect this?

All my data:

[image: All my data]

Answer (score 0):

You need to unpivot the data in Power Query first and then based on the new table create the PivotTable:

[image]

Comment: You're the best!!!! This worked perfectly. I really appreciate it!

Comment: Is there a non `Power Query` way to achieve this?