# Excel Pivot table only counting first column

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, pivot-table

### The Issue

I'm trying to count instances of a number in each column. For a simgle column of data, this works fine, but when I add more columns, the count always reflects the first column.

Attached is a minimal example of the issue I'm facing:

[image: Minimal example showing column A being counted for both column A & B]

### What I Am Doing

1. I am selecting the entire data set (which in reality is much bigger) and inserting a pivot table.
2. I am not ticking the box labelled `Add this data to the Data Model` in the dialog that pops up.
3. in the `PivotTable Fields` pane on the right I am adding my columns of data to the `VALUES` quadrant and selecting `Count of <A/B...>`.
4. In the column quadrant a field named `VALUES` automatically appears.
5. I add one of the columns to the `ROWS` quadrant.
6. I then go on to group the rows (not shown in this minimal example)

### What I Have Tried

- Adding both column `FIELDS` to the `ROWS` quadrant of the `PivotTable Fields` pane on the right, but this creates a strange nested "Row Lables" column.
- Adding a seperate column for the values to be counted.
- `Count Of Numbers` instead of `Count`
- Various tutorials on how to correctly achieve this for a single column, in case I was doing it wrong.
- [Pivot Table won't show correct data relating to the row names](https://superuser.com/questions/1349450/pivot-table-wont-show-correct-data-relating-to-the-row-names) appears to do what I want, but I don't seem to have access to PowerQuery.

## Update

After looking at [How to "unpivot" or "reverse pivot" in Excel?](https://superuser.com/questions/78439/how-to-unpivot-or-reverse-pivot-in-excel) I now have [image: Minimal example showing column A being cut off].

Clearly this is much closer to what I want (and I can turn off the grand totals in the pivot table's settings easily enough) but it is now bizarrely ignoring the first column. *(A blank column to the left of the range fixes it, but I have no idea why...)*

Comment: This is how pivot works by design. You need to unpivot your data first.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I suppose my issue is that I don't really understand what it means for data to be "pivoted", could you explain?